# Responding to button click events in Google Docs custom HTML dialog

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am an Admin of a Google Spreadsheet. Several times a week me and other admins have to add new users to the spreadsheet so I thought it would be easier if we could use a custom HTML dialog to do so.

I am displaying the dialog like so:

```
function AddRow()
{
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddRow')
                  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Add Row') 
}
```

File AddRow.html is a simple HTML form with text boxes, select elements, etc.

Now is there a way I can access the spreadsheet to add a new row with the values entered by the user?

In the HTML file AddRow.html I tried the following

```
<script>
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('2015');
    sheet.insertRows(2, 1);
</script>
```

However this does not insert a row. If I move that code of the HTML file into a *.gs file it does work so it must be a limitation on HTML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script code within served HTML files is javascript, not Google Apps Script - the main difference for this question is that server-side Google Apps Script has access to the full set of APIs provided for Google Services, while the client-side javascript does not.

One option is to use the [`google.script.run` Client-side API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to invoke the function that you already have working on the server side (in the editor). For more information, see the [guide to communicating with server functions in HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

```js
function insertRows(rowIndex, numRows) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('2015');
  sheet.insertRows(rowIndex, numRows);
  return true;     // Need to have a return value for google.script.run to work
  // To return a failure to the client side, throw an error.
}
```

Client side script:

```js
...
// Call insertRows on server side.
google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler( hooray )  // See function hooray below
      .insertRows(2, 1);
...

/**
 * This function will receive a call-back if the google.script.run
 * call returns success.
 */
function hooray( result ) {
  alert( "Received result <" + result + ">" );
}
```